# Neural network as a surrogate model - finding an optimum of it's output space

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to find optimal values of parameters of some device (usually like 4 to 25 parameters) by predicting properties of the device (voltage and resistance, we want the lowest possible resistance and voltage higher than some value). I used a neural network as a surrogate model, trained on hundreds of observations (not more, the software that simulates those devices is computationally expensive). Inputs are those parameters and outputs are voltage and resistance, it's a regression task.

The surrogate model gives me nice predictions (R_squared above 0.92), so what I now have to do is to find the best parameters, that, according to that surrogate model, give lowest possible resistance and voltage higher than the value. The output space can be optimized using simulated annealing, genetic algorithms, or hill climbing, but I was wondering - is there a way to use the fact that a neural network is a differentiable function? I mean, when training the network through back propagation, we get derivations of the loss with respect to weights, is there a way to get derivations of some new loss calculated from voltage and resistance with respect to inputs, and use this information during the optimization? I feel like SA, GA and HC are very crude.

If a method like this does not exist or is very difficult to implement (in python, tensorflow), what would be the best implementation of genetic algorithms? scipy.optimize.differential_evolution seems good but I've seen that there are some dedicated libraries to GAs.

Comment: Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info , and notice that recommendations of libraries etc are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: There were multiple tags and most importantly, asking for a library was not the main question, I was asking if some specific algorithm exists, which belongs to machine-learning. However if there really is a problem with it, I changed the flair.

Comment: Please notice that the issue of a question being on-topic here or not has to do only with the *content* of the question, and it can never be resolved by tag manipulation alone - let alone that the same note exists in the tag descriptions of `deep-learning` and `data0science`, too. The point here was *not* to remove the tag, but to inform you for other SE sites where such questions may be on-topic.